# Make required character in repeating pattern optional only at the end of the string

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex to match a repeating pattern:

```
/([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2};)+/
```

It'll match strings like: `9:9;` (1 set of numbers) or `12:2;4:9;` (2 sets of numbers) or `5:2;7:7;5:2;` (3 sets of numbers), and so on.

So far so good, but I need the semi-colon to be required to separate each set, while optional if it's at the end of the line. So I need it to accept both this: `5:2;7:7;5:2;` and this: `5:2;7:7;5:2`. This: `9:9;` and this: `9:9`.

How might this be achieved?

Comment: I know you asked for Regex, but you tagged this as PHP as well. Why not just `$numbers = explode(';', $setOfNumbers);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(;|$)` so the ending `;` is optional

```
/([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}(;|$))+/
```

---

To avoid capturing `;` you can use `(?:;|$)`. 

`?:` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/5447994)

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you! Will accept in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
^(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2};?)+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dQ9vA5/1).
`\d` matches `0-9`, `;?` matches a semicolon *if it is there* , `^` and `$` are anchors for a line.